# Castelnouvo-Mumford Regularity

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings

I'm learning Castelnouvo-Mumford regularity of associated graded ring. As u see in 2 pics below, **Lemma 3.3**.

- $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ is a Noetherian ring local, $\dim(A)=1$; $\mathfrak{q}=(x)$ is a parameter ideal of $A$ ($\mathfrak{q}$ is a parameter ideal mean that $\mathfrak{q}$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal of $A$ and generated by $n=\dim(A)$ element(s)).
- $G_\mathfrak{q}(A)=A/\mathfrak{q}\oplus \mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{q^2} \oplus \mathfrak{q^2}/\mathfrak{q^3} \oplus \cdots$ is the associated graded ring of $A$ respect ideal $\mathfrak{q}$; $\operatorname{reg}(G_\mathfrak{q}(A))$ is the Castelnouvo-Mumford regularity of $G_\mathfrak{q}(A)$; $p(G_\mathfrak{q}(A))$ is the postulation number of $G_\mathfrak{q}(A)$.

In this proof, because $\operatorname{depth}(A) \leq \dim(A)$ and $\dim(A)=1$ so we have $\operatorname{depth}(A)=0$ or $\operatorname{depth}(A)=1$.

- If $\operatorname{depth}(A)=1$ we will prove that $\operatorname{reg}(G_\mathfrak{q}(A))=0$ and $p(G_\mathfrak{q}(A))=-1$
- If $\operatorname{depth}(A)=0$ we will prove that $\operatorname{reg}(G_\mathfrak{q}(A))=p(G_\mathfrak{q}(A))$

So my questions are:

1. Why $\oplus (x^n,L)/(x^{n+1},L)=\oplus (x^n)/(x^{n+1},x^nL)$? and same with $K$. Are these equations from a theorem,...? Moreover please explain about maps in the exact sequence.
2. Where do I can find the equations about $\operatorname{length}$ as you see in $H_{\mathfrak{q}}(n-1)$?
3. In this proof, with $M$ is a $A$-module, $I=(x)$ is a submodule of M can I replace $G_\mathfrak{q}(A)$ by $G_I(M)=\oplus I^nM/I^{n+1}M$ and we have: $\operatorname{reg}(G_I(M))=p(G_I(M))+\operatorname{depth}(M)$?

Thanks for your regarding!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok, this is "Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity postulation number and relation types"- Makus Broadmann and Cao Huy Linh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Actually $(x^n,L)/(x^{n+1},L)$ is *isomorphic* to $(x^n)/(x^{n+1},x^nL)$. This isn't hard to prove: take the map $(x^n)\hookrightarrow (x^n,L)\to(x^n,L)/(x^{n+1},L)$ whose kernel is $(x^n)\cap(x^{n+1},L)$. Use that $L:x=L$ in order to prove that $(x^n)\cap(x^{n+1},L)=(x^{n+1},x^nL)$.
   Similar arguments work for $K$.
   About the exact sequence: the $n$th graded piece of $G_q(A)$ is $(x^n)/(x^{n+1})$ and we have a surjection $(x^n)/(x^{n+1})\to(x^n)/(x^{n+1},x^nL)$ whose kernel is $(x^{n+1},x^nL)/(x^{n+1})$.
2. The first equality is the definition, the second comes from the short exact sequence $0\to(x^n,L)/(x^n)\to A/(x^n)\to A/(x^n,L)\to 0$, for the third use the isomorphism theorems for rings, and the last is obvious.
3. I suppose that you want to extend Lemma 3.3 to modules. Well, first of all $x\in A$ should be $M$-regular and $\dim M=1$. Now remark that the regularity behaves well for modules, too (see my first comment below). Finally I think you have chances to generalize the lemma to modules, but I leave you to check all the details.

Comment: Thank so much. Please explain some problems:
1. If $\operatorname{depth}(A)=1$ why $\operatorname{reg}(G_\mathfrak{q}(A))=0$ and $p(G_\mathfrak{q}(A))=-1$ from the isomorphic?
2. Why: $A/L$ is Cohen-Macaulay and $\operatorname{reg}G_\mathfrak{q}(A))=0$?
3. In this proof can I replace $G_\mathfrak{q}(A))$ by $G_I(M))=\oplus I^nM/I^{n+1}M$ and we have: $\operatorname{reg}(G_I(M))=p(G_I(M))+\operatorname{depth}(M)?$

Comment: 1. For basic properties of regularity see [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206133652). There you can find (in Corollary 5) that $reg(M/aM)=reg(M)$ if $a$ is a homogeneous $M$-regular element of degree one. Apply this result to $M=(A/xA)[X]$ and $a=X$. It's also known a similar formula for the postulation number: $p(M/aM)=p(M)+1$.

Comment: 2. Since $x$ is a nzd on $A/L$ it follows that depth $A/L\ge 1$; but $\dim A/L\le\dim A=1$, so $A/L$ is CM 1-dimensional. For the regularity of the associated graded ring of $A/L$ (I think this is what you asked), just replace $A$ by $A/L$ in the above comment.